# Canvas drawImage bad performance

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Hi everyone in my case I have a large destination canvas and a small offscreen canvas.

The offscreen one is under 100x100 whereas the destination one is 5000x5000. When I call drawImage to copy the smaller canvas into the destination canvas I get a huge memory spike and performance is terrible.

I tried converting the smaller canvas to an image and this made the performance a lot faster where it was actually use able. The only problem with this is that an image needs time to load so when the onload is called my canvas context changed. --- exif data might be ignored too which would explain the different orientation of the image.

Is there a way to strip properties off the canvas context so that I could save and reset all the context properties in the onload?

I tried to do object.keys but it always return an empty array. I think my only approach left would be to draw directly on the destination instead of doing offscreen. It seems to be quicker but I'd need to redo all the calculations.

Are there any other alternatives I could try doing?

Thanks!

The render function below is called a few times a second.

```
fabObject._render = function(ctx) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 100;
  canvas.height = 100;
  var ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
  myDrawFn() //this function draws to the new canvas. Performance is the same with this function commented or uncommented
  ctx.drawImage(ctx2, 0,0)// This line causes performance to be terrible. I tried converting ctx2 to an image first and passing it in but the onload places the image in the wrong orientation. I'm guessing its not using the exif data.

}
```

Update:
I also tried doing fillRect per pixel and this was also a lot faster. However when I applied shadow properties, it got super slow. I'm assuming this is due to shadows having high pixel density, but I'm not sure.

So I did further testing and its actually the shadow blur that is causing the slow down when I use the drawing by pixel method. Without the blur, having a shadow is quick.

Comment: You should not get this memory spike to start with. There is probably something going wrong in here. Could you share an [MCVE] reproducing the issue ? drawImage is the natural and most optimized way to draw one canvas on an other.

Comment: So I commented out the entire function. I only left the creation of the second canvas with document.createElement('canvas'). Then I set its size and called drawImage() directly. Even without any other drawing functions being called, copying an empty canvas to my destination canvas is extremely slow.

Comment: Could show a working sample of your code ? In your question, you can add a working snippet. Or there is some online services, like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @user6728767 Have you looked at disabling `renderOnAddRemove` when your copy smaller canvas into the destination canvas, http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#renderOnAddRemove?

Comment: Yeah I'll post a sample snippet in a few minutes. Is renderOnAddRemove a flag that is only settable on fabric objects? This function in particular is an override of my fabric objects render function. This render function is called every few seconds. Would this be something I have to set when I instantiate the objeft or can I set it before calling drawImage then unset it?

Comment: Ah it looks like, renderOnAddRemove is already disabled on my destination canvas.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be from reusing the same offscreen canvas. If I call drawImage on a new canvas every time like my example above. There seems to be no memory leak or slowdown. Is there any reason why using the same offscreen canvas in drawImage would cause a memory leak?